# When using OpenVPN, can I get the client device to have an IP address from the local network?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I've been using OpenVPN recently and it's been working great.

However, I have daemon running on my Raspberry Pi which offers a web interface. This web interface has an IP address whitelist, which includes 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.*.*.

When using OpenVPN, my client device can reach the website just fine, but is informed that it doesn't match the IP address whitelist.

Is there anyway I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can either configure OpenVPN to bridge mode, then the VPN clients will get IP address from `192.168` network, or you can add OpenVPN IP address space to whitelist. The default address space is `10.8.0.0/24`.